# read method in spring batch is not invoked

Tags: spring-batch

I am beginner in spring batch. I have written a code in which records gets downloaded from a 3rd party as per requirement and it gets written in a file.
Problem I am facing that read method of the reader is not getting invoked however the method written in `@BeforeStep` is getting invoked.

Can anyone please help me with?

Thanks in advance.

Code I am using to launch Job:

```
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
context.setConfigLocation("applicationContext.xml");
JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) 
context.getBean("jobLauncher");
Job job = (Job) context.getBean("myJob");
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<batch:job id="myJob">   
<batch:step id="step1" >   
<batch:tasklet>
<batch:chunk reader="jobReader"  writer="jobWriter" commit-interval="1" />  
</batch:tasklet>             
</batch:step>          
</batch:job>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to add some code?

Comment: Mixing Annotation (javaconfig) and xml config should be avoided to prevent undesiderable effects.
Use `<listener>` instead

Comment: so if your listener gets kicked that means your job started successfully. As next step, you need to show your reader code to see if there is anything wrong there.Also, how do you know that reader method was not invoked?